# GPT-2: Setting biases as -1 billion

Tags: python, nlp, gpt-2

I'm currently trying to predict upcoming words given an input text chunk, but I want to "mask" the last *n* words of the input text by setting the attention weights to 0 (or something very small).

This is what I tried to do:

I tried modifying the biases on all layers of my GPT-2 model by setting them to a very small value for all tokens I want to mask. I read that you *add* the bias values to the dot-product of query and key vectors, so I figured they have to be negative and ideally very small in order to make the resulting attention weight as small as possible. In a [blog post](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-gpt2/) on self-attention I read that you can use either -inf or -1 billion (in GPT), but if I use any values < -1, I get errors, possibly because I produce values that are so small that they produce underflow (although I think it's odd that -1 is basically the minimum cutoff value I can still use, that's not that small).

This is what I'd need advice on:

a) Does changing the biases like that make sense? I'm a newbie GPT-user so I'm always a little unsure whether what I do is correct.

b) If my approach makes sense, why can't I use values < -1? Is there a way to use smaller values?

c) If not and I use -1, would that still work to reduce the attention
weights to something around 0?

This is my code:

```
# import modules
!pip install transformers

import numpy as np
import math

import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import torch

# download pre-trained German GPT-2 model & tokenizer from the Hugging Face model hub
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dbmdz/german-gpt2")

# initialise the model, use end-of-sequence (EOS) token as padding tokens
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("dbmdz/german-gpt2", pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id)



# set the input text and the number of words to mask
input_text = ["Orlando", "liebte", "von", "Natur", "aus", "einsame", "Orte,", "weite", "Ausblicke", "und", "das", "Gefühl,", "für", "immer", "und", "ewig"] # allein zu sein.
n = 5  # I want to mask the last n words
print("masking the following", n, "words now:", )

# 1 word can consist of many tokens, so get last n words 
# and tokenize them so we know how many tokens we have to mask:
masked_words = input_text[-n:]
n_tokens = len(tokenizer.tokenize(" ".join(masked_words)))
print(" ".join(masked_words))

# encode the full input text (including the words we want to mask) and get the attention mask
encoded_input = tokenizer.encode_plus(" ".join(input_text),
                                      add_special_tokens = False,  # don't add special tokens
                                      return_attention_mask = True,  # return the attention mask for the current text input
                                      return_tensors='pt')  # return output as PyTorch tensor object

# get attention mask from encoded input
attention_mask = encoded_input['attention_mask']

# check how many attention weights there are in the mask.
# mask_length should be number of tokens in the full sentence
mask_length = attention_mask.size()[1]

# Create new attention mask where the weights for the last n tokens are 
# set to - 1 billion

# Mask the last n words by setting them to - 1 billion, 
# but leave last token set to 1 (for the space after the last masked word)
# attention_mask[:, -(n_tokens + 1): -1] = -1 # this works
attention_mask[:, -(n_tokens + 1): -1] = -100000000 # this doesn't work
#print(attention_mask)


# Now we want to modify the attention weights on all layers by changing 
# the biases to our attention mask values there.

# Loop modules in model.transformer
# (all attention layers are modules in the transformer)
# Find attention modules and set our custom attention mask as biases 
for module in model.transformer.modules():
  # if the current module is a MultiHeadAttention object (aka an attention module)...
  if isinstance(module, torch.nn.MultiheadAttention):
    # set attention mask we defined earlier as the biases
    module.register_buffer("bias", attention_mask.unsqueeze(0))

# Get prediction from full model:
# use ids from input text (input_ids) & the modified attention mask to generate the output
output = model.generate(encoded_input['input_ids'], 
                        attention_mask = attention_mask,
                        max_new_tokens = 10)

# get the predicted token ID and the corresponding text string
predicted_text = tokenizer.decode(output[0], 
                                  skip_special_tokens = True)


# print the predicted text
print("\n Predicted text:", predicted_text)
```

Thanks in advance for your help/ideas/comments!

Comment: Still don't know the answers to these questions, but I found out it's easier to use an attention mask to set the attention weights of certain tokens to 0 on all layers instead of doing it indirectly by modifying the biases.